# Is there a more efficient way to combine a date and time in swift 5?

Tags: swift

I have function which receives 2 strings the first is a date "y-M-d" and the second a time "HH:mm". I then combine them using the following code.

```swift
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "y-M-d"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let time = dateFormatter.date(from: timeStr)!
    let calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .iso8601)
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.day = calendar.component(.day, from: date) //split from date above
    components.month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    components.year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    components.hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: time) //split from time above
    components.minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: time)
    let newDate = calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)
```

The code all works fine and is doing what I want it to. However, I was wondering if anyone can suggest a slicker way of doing it, using less lines of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the date & time strings and parse them in one go:

```
let dateStr = "2020-03-12"
let timeStr = "15:35"

let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "y-M-d HH:mm"
let date = df.date(from: dateStr + " " + timeStr)

// prints: 2020-03-12 13:35:00 +0000 (my machine is GMT+2)
```

**Edit**: As Leo Dabus said in the comments, a more appropriate format for the provided strings should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` (just kept the provided format from the question). The spirit of the answer was not to propose a format but to provide a way to avoid parsing date/time separately.

Comment: This  might crash the app if the user device 24h time settings os set to 12h

Comment: Btw  M is for 1-12 for 01-12 you should use MM. The same applies for the date

Comment: @LeoDabus You're right. My example doesn't propose a format (merely uses the provided one, but I will edit the answer thanks!). To be honest I don't really understand how this could crash, provided that I'm formatting static strings... can you elaborate?

Comment: When working with fixed format dates, such as RFC 3339, you set the dateFormat property to specify a format string. For most fixed formats, you should also set the locale property to a POSIX locale ("en_US_POSIX"), and set the timeZone property to UTC. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: if you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed format. In most cases the best locale to choose is "en_US_POSIX", a locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results **regardless of both user and system preferences.**

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks I appreciate it. Again, you're right I could have set a locale (based on my input - in this case is a static one) & a timezone (as stated in my answer this was implied & interpreted as local time). I just felt that all this was out of the scope of the answer. Also, my bad for not checking for an existing answer. Thanks for pointing out though 

Answer (score 2):

Simply get a combined String using date and time. Then use that String to get the Date instance from it.

```
func getDate(d: String, t: String) -> Date? {
    let str = d + t
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "y-M-dHH:mm"
    let date = formatter.date(from: str)
    return date
}
```

Comment: This might crash the app if the user device 24h time settings os set to 12h